# overlay discrete and continuous layer in ggplot - surprised that layer order matters

Tags: r, ggplot2

consider the following example dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d = mtcars %>% 
 as_tibble(rownames = "name") %>% 
 mutate(wt.cat = cut(wt, seq(1.5, 5.5, by = 1))) %>%
 group_by(wt.cat) %>%
 summarize(
   Mean = mean(mpg),
   Min = min(mpg),
   Max = max(mpg)
 )
```

Say I want to plot points for the "mean" value of each category in `wt.cat` and a ribbon showing the range. This works:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = wt.cat)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y= Mean)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = as.numeric(wt.cat), ymin = Min, ymax = Max), fill = "blue")
```

[image: example 1]

But the points are masked by the ribbon. However, if I change the order of the layers so that the points are plotted on top of the ribbon, I get an error:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = wt.cat)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = as.numeric(wt.cat), ymin = Min, ymax = Max), fill = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(y= Mean))
## Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

So even though I'm specifying the discrete axis as the "default" aesthetic, it gets overridden by the specification of the first plotted layer. The only way I can find around this is to plot a dummy point layer first:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = wt.cat)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y= Mean), shape = NA) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = as.numeric(wt.cat), ymin = Min, ymax = Max), fill = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(y= Mean))
## Warning message:
## Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image: example 2]

Is there a more "proper" or correct way of combining discrete and continuous layers? Is there a solution that doesn't require creating a dummy layer?

Comment: I guess the ribbon won't draw with a discrete scale on the x-axis, right? Could you just use a continuous x-axis and then set the labels to show up as intervals?

Comment: @camille I could, but it's complicated because I need to set both the breaks and the labels in that case, so I need to do something like `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(levels(d$wt.cat)), labels = levels(d$wt.cat))`. There are additional complications when the plot is produced at the end of a pipe, since I can't easily access other columns of the data within the ggplot call itself.

Comment: I think you might be stuck saving your data frame in order to refer back to it in making the plot. If you're willing to do that, you can make a continuous variable to use instead of `wt.cat`; in this example, it could be the midpoint of each interval. Alternatively, if there's a pattern to making the categories that you could put in a function, you might be able to use that to set the labels

Answer (score 0):

would something like this be a solution?

```
d %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(x = wt.cat)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = levels(.$wt.cat)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x =as.numeric(wt.cat), ymin = Min, ymax = Max), fill = "blue")  +
    geom_point(aes(y=Mean)) 
}
```

I just learned you can wrap a pipe with `{ }` and then reference the entire data frame with `.`

As camille said, the issue is that `geom_ribbon` requires a continuous scale because it plots area across values relating to the adjacent position. I believe the scale gets converted to continuous when `geom_ribbon` is added, but the labels are maintained.

Hope this helps

As per my reply -- the following works just as well if you want `ggplot2` to handle all the labeling

```
d %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = wt.cat)) + 
        scale_x_discrete() +
        geom_ribbon(aes(x =as.numeric(wt.cat), ymin = Min, ymax = Max), fill = "blue")  +
        geom_point(aes(y=Mean))
```

Comment: It works, but in some ways it's messier than the dummy layer solution. I wish `ggplot2` had `rlang`-like support for access the plot data using the `.data` pronoun.

Comment: Is the main problem that there isn't a 'clean' way to access data when piping? What exactly is the end goal?

Comment: The problem is that for this trivial example strategies like `levels(.$wt.cat)` can work, but in other cases it is much easier to rely on `ggplot2` to automatically make decisions on labeling based on the data itself. However, it turns out that the automatic choices depend on layer *order* rather than the aesthetic definitions in the ggplot object, which is surprising.

Comment: I disagree. If `.` is the vector in question then `ggplot2` decision for labeling is essentially `levels(.)` for a factor vector or `sort(unique(.))` for a character vector. Thus you could easily replicate this feature with an `ifelse` statement. This is besides the point because you do not need `labels = levels(.$wt.cat)` you just need to have `scale_x_discrete()` as your first addition. The axis labels are defined by the first `geom`/`stat`/`scale` provided. This is why if `geom_ribbon` is your first layer, the scale is coerced to continuous, then `ggplot2` can't map discrete to continuous.